Does this elliptic curve over a cyclotomic tower have finitely many integral points?
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})$, also written as $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty})$ or $\mathbb{Q}(p^\infty)$, denotes $\mathbb{Q}$ adjoined with the $p^{n}$th roots of unity for all $n$. It's the union of a cylotomic tower, and it's studied in subjects like Iwosawa theory and class field theory.
Let $R$ be the ring of integers of this field, and let $\lambda$ be a nonzero element of $R$.
My question is, are there always only finitely many ordered pars $(x,y)$ of elements of $R$ such that $y^2-x^3+8\lambda x=0$?  Or does there exist a $\lambda$ for which there are infinitely many such ordered pairs?

Do you know what happens for rational points?
